# How to get the text of a input box which is showing value from backend

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver. My test case is 
Select a address on shipping page which inturn shows the details of the address in different fields below.
Now I want to check whatever the text is coming on those field is correct or not?
Problem is niether it is coming as a text nor a value on that particular field.  So get text or getattribute ("value") is not working.
It is coming from javascript written on it and I am not able to inspect it.
Please help

Comment: Is there some code you can post for a look by a second set of eyes?

Comment: Code is simple String text = driver.findelement(by.xpath("xpath")).gettext(); but problem is that element is not showing the value, which is appearing, as a text

Comment: That's interesting, can you provide url?

Comment: No, it's an official site. Problem is, that is an input box showing some value prepopulated and I want to verify that value but that value is not in html code, its coming from dojo script

Comment: gettext() or getText()?

Comment: No, you cannot use Selenium for this task. Selenium is designed to automate web-based applications on different browsers. I cannot interact with non HTML popups as in your case.

Comment: Actually, I figured out. The field was showing values fetched by javascript so I ran the same javascript using javascript executor.

JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String val = (String) js.executeScript("return $(\".id of field.val()");
then used val for my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured out. The field was showing values fetched by javascript so I ran the same javascript using javascript executor.

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
String val = (String) js.executeScript("return $(\".id of field.val()");
```

then used val for my function.